# Find $\ker(T)$, where $T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\to M_2(\mathbb{R})$ by the following:

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find $\ker(T)$, where $T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\to M_2(\mathbb{R})$ by $T(f)=\begin{bmatrix}f'(0)&2f(1)\\0&f''(2)\end{bmatrix}$

Let us consider any $f$.

$f=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\in P_3\mathbb(R)$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$

$T(f)=T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=\begin{bmatrix}0&2a+2b+2c+d\\0&12a+2b\end{bmatrix}$(*)

Now we know that $\ker(T)=\{f\in P_3(\mathbb{R})|T(f)=0\in M_2\mathbb(R)\}$

So we just let $T(f)=0$ matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix}0&2a+2b+2c+d\\0&12a+2b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Solving:

$2a+2b+2c+d=0$

$12a+2b=0$

We get:

Solution: $sp\{\begin{bmatrix}(1/5)\\(-6/5)\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}(1/10)\\(-3/5)\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$ with $\dim$ 2

I know the rank equation says rank + nullity = number of columns, but here nullity is $2$, and from $(*)$ the matrix looks like it has rank $0$, since no columns can have pivots. So the equation holds.

Have I done this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Jiaqi Li the error in $f'(0)$ gave you an extra vector in the basis for $\ker(T)$ (the second one). Here is a solution for general $n$.

$$\ker(T)= \{f: Tf = \left (\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)\}.$$

Therefore, $f \in\ker(T)$ if and only if $f'(0)=f(1)=f''(2)=0$.

Let $f\in \ker(T)$. Then  $f=a_0+a_1 x+ \dots +a_n x^n$ for some $a_0,\dots,a_n$.

1. Since $f'(0)=a_1$, we have 
   $$ a_1=0.$$
2. Since $f(1)= a_0+ a_1+\dots+a_n$, and $a_1=0$, it follows that 
   $$a_0 =-\sum_{j\ge 2} a_j.$$
3. Since $f''(2) =\sum_{j\ge 2} j(j-1)a_j 2^j$, it follows that 
   $$\sum_{j\ge 2} j(j-1) a_j2^{j-2}=0.$$

Combining all three, we conclude, that $a_1=0,a_0 = -(a_2+\dots+a_n)$ and 
$a_2=-\sum_{j\ge3} j(j-1) 2^{j-3}$. Therefore,

$$f = (-\sum_{j\ge 3} a_j + \sum_{j\ge3} j(j-1) a_j 2^{j-3}) -(\sum_{j\ge3} j(j-1) a_j 2^{j-3} )x^2+\sum_{j\ge 3} a_j x^j.$$

That is

$$\ker(T)=  \mbox{Span} \left\{ x^j-j(j-1)2^{j-3}(x^2-1)-1:j=3,\dots,n\right\}.$$

In particular for $n=3$, we have $\ker(T) = \mbox{Span}\{x^3-6x^2+5\}$.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply the dimension of the range is $2$ though? ... which it is. thanks

Comment: Dimension of $P_3$ is $4=3+1$.  Dimension of the kernel is $1$. Dimension of the range is  $4-1=3$ (it contains all upper triangular matrices). In general for every $n\ge 3$,  $\dim P_n=n+1$,  $\dim \ker(T)=n-2$, and therefore $\dim R(T) = 3$.

Comment: How would you mathetmtically show that your range is 3 though?

Comment: Either by 1. Dimension formula $\dim R(T)+\dim \ker(T)=\dim P_3$; or by 2. A basis for the range is $T1,Tx,Tx^2$, and it is easy to check that they span upper triangular matrices.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in the calculation. Note that
$$f'(0)=c$$
instead of $f'(0)=0$. The other parts of your solution are good.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up